# Change template members based on numeric parameters?

Tags: c++, templates

I'd like to be able to accomplish something like this:

```
template<int size>
struct myStruct
{
    (size > 5 ? int64_t : int32_t) value;
};
```

One way of doing it would be to make an explicit specialisation for every possible set of values, but this obviously isn't ideal. Is anyone aware of a better way?

Comment: why would  template here?

Comment: What you have is not _"isn't ideal"_, but simply not compiling. You cannot use the ternary condition operator to select a type.

Comment: I'm aware, hence this question, and my qualifier "something like this", not "why doesn't this compile"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `std::conditional`. This requires C++11, but you could easily write your own:

```
template<int size>
struct myStruct
{
    typename std::conditional<(size > 5), int64_t, int32_t>::type
          value;
};
```

Or in C++14:

```
template<int size>
struct myStruct
{
    std::conditional_t<(size > 5), int64_t, int32_t> value;
};
```